# How to calculate moment of inertia double rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

How to calculate moment of ineria of disk if it has double rotation, shown on picture below.

[image]

Comment: I guess it depends upon the axis about which u want to calculate

Comment: for rotation around blue axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem)

$$I = I_{cm} + mr^2$$

where $I_{cm}$ is the moment of inertia of the disc and $I$ is the moment of inertia with respect to the athlete, $m$ is a mass of the disc and $r$ is the perpendicular distance between the athlete’s axis and the axis of the disk.

So if you can calculate the moment of inertia of the disc and have the other values above, the rest should be straightforward.

Comment: your answer is not complete what about the rotation of the disc around the centre (red arrow)

Comment: That is what $I$ represents. Did you read my answer?

Comment: yes I did, but it is wrong

Comment: You only accounted for the rotatin marked with blue arrow

Comment: There are TWO rotation axes. One for the discus and for the thrower. So please explain how it is wrong.